# Javascript: Add nodes dynamically in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

How can I dynamically add nodes in jstree?

You can prefer the link http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm.

```
$(function () {
    $("#alarm-treeview").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : 
        {
            "data" : 
            [
                {
                    "data" : "PI_SERVER1", 
                    "attr" : { "id" : "root.id" }, 
                     "children" : [ { "data" : "Alarms",
                                     "attr" : { "id" : "Alarms.id" },
                                     "children" : [ ] },
                                     { "data" : "Events",
                                     "attr" : { "id" : "Events.id" },
                                     "children" : [ ] }
                                 ]
                },
            ]
            $("#PI_SERVER1").jstree("create","#phtml_1","first",true);
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm" ] 
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ... please format your question properly. Also, it seems what you are trying to do is described in the documentation you mentioned (http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm). Have you encountered any problems when you tried what is described there?

Comment: Ah... the line `$("#PI_SERVER1").jstree("create","#phtml_1","first",true);` is just not valid there. You cannot execute arbitrary code inside an object literal. You'd execute it some time after you initialised the plugin.

Comment: ya you r right . i have initialised all plugins already.